# Classifying image documents using Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to classify image documents(like Passport, Driving Licence etc) using Machine Learning.
Does anybody has any link or documents where I can get idea to do this task.

What I am thinking is of first converting the document to text format and then fro Text file extract the information.But this I can do with one file at a time.
I want to know how can I perform this in millions of document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert documents to text, you can do this with images directly.

To do image classification you can build basic CNNs with Keras library.

https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-convolutional-neural-network-cnn-in-keras-329fbbadc5f5

This basic CNN will be enough for you to train an image classifier. But you want to get state of the art accuracy, I recommend get a pretrained resnet50 and train it to build an image classifier. Other than accuracy, there is another major advantage of using pre trained network, you'll need less data to train a robust image classifier.

https://engmrk.com/kerasapplication-pre-trained-model/?utm_campaign=News&utm_medium=Community&utm_source=DataCamp.com

The only thing that you'll need to change is number of output classes from 1000 to the number of classes you want.