# i want to write script which find driving license from documents in image formate. can i found it from Python using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, artificial-intelligence, tesseract

I have several documents in one folder and I want to write the script to find the driving license in this folder automatically.
I have also written a script in python using OpenCV but it not working.
can anyone tell me what can I do will to write a script?

Answer (score 0):

use glob library so you can extract all the images of your driving license from that folder
[use of glob](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-glob-function-to-find-files-recursively-in-python/)

another StackOverflow question that will help you [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module)

after this write your OpenCV logic to get licenses from images

please edit your question the way you asked is not correct

Comment: I have a website where user upload own driving license so whether I want to identify the uploading file. that it's driving license or not

Comment: [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068790/classifying-image-documents-using-machine-learning)  here if you have to classify images